# Can an electroweak plasma exist at room temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, plasma-physics, quark-gluon-plasma

Above around 246 GeV ($10^{15}$ Kelvin), the weak and electromagnetic forces are thought to be merged. See [Electroweak interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction). This is thought to occur in the cores of over dense neutron stars and to have occurred when the universe was around $10^{12}$ seconds old. Low temperature plasmas can be created, see [Cold Plasmas](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/physics-and-astronomy/cold-plasmas#:%7E:text=Low%2Dtemperature%20plasmas%20are%20generated,and%20of%20ultra%20large%2Dscale). Can an electoroweak plasma?

Comment: Cold plasmas often exist not because the plasma was initially created cold, but rather that it was cooled over time and/or the electrons did not recombine yet.  This is in the sub-eV to maybe 10 eV range.  If your initial energy is $10^{11}$ eV, that is a completely different system as both the electrons and protons/ions are going to be relativistic in just their thermal energies...

Comment: I mistyped 10^ -12 seconds as 10^12 seconds. Is there a way to correct it above?